# new content type with fields for username and password

Tags: 7, entities, users

I have a requirement for creating a new content type and creating a new user through that.

The content type have fields like 'name', 'address' etc. but the client wants to have username and password field in that, so that the user could be created along with it.

I am a bit lost with this, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Configuration->People->Account settings->Manage fields` in the menu (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) you can add fields to the User entity, such as name and address.

Fields added to the User entity has a settings whether they should be displayed on user registration form.

Comment: Ok, and how could I hook those fields in the new content type creation then?

Comment: The fields will be added to the User entity. Why do you need another content type to store name, address etc?

Comment: I see your point, and could I assign a role to that User entity too?

Comment: Yes, but that's another story https://drupal.org/project/registration_role :)